# AVAsset is not cutting correct with time

Tags: objective-c, avfoundation, avasset

I have this code:

```
float seconds = CMTimeGetSeconds(editableAsset.duration);

        AVMutableComposition *thirtMutableComposition = [AVMutableComposition composition];

        if (assetVideoTrack != nil) {
            AVMutableCompositionTrack *compositionVideoTrack = [thirtMutableComposition addMutableTrackWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo preferredTrackID:kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid];
            AVAssetTrack *videoAssetTrack= [[editableAsset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo] lastObject];
            compositionVideoTrack.preferredTransform = videoAssetTrack.preferredTransform;
            [compositionVideoTrack insertTimeRange:CMTimeRangeMake(CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(1, NSEC_PER_SEC), CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(seconds, NSEC_PER_SEC)) ofTrack:assetVideoTrack atTime:kCMTimeZero error:nil];

        }

        if (assetAudioTrack != nil) {
            AVMutableCompositionTrack *compositionAudioTrack = [thirtMutableComposition addMutableTrackWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio preferredTrackID:kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid];
            [compositionAudioTrack insertTimeRange:CMTimeRangeMake(CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(1, NSEC_PER_SEC), CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(seconds, NSEC_PER_SEC)) ofTrack:assetAudioTrack atTime:kCMTimeZero error:nil];

        }
```

It doesn't work. The strange thing about it: If I use:

```
float seconds = 10;
```

Instead of the first line it works fine. But the float value in the first part is exactly 10 seconds.

Can you help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your calls to `CMTimeRangeMake()` look strange in two ways:

First, you're removing 1 second from the asset, so you should reduce the duration by 1 second too:

```
CMTimeRangeMake(CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(1, NSEC_PER_SEC), CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(seconds-1, NSEC_PER_SEC))
```

Second, your use of `NSEC_PER_SEC` for the `preferredTimescale` of those calls to `CMTimeMakeWithSeconds` looks suspect. 10<sup>9</sup> seems kinda large. Why not try with with something like 600? e.g.

```
CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(1, 600)
```